# How do I replace my instances with Easymock

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I am trying to unit test a class using EasyMock. To simplify things, I have made an example below. What I want is for the StringBuilder instance to be replaced by the EasyMock instance during testing. (As it is not the functionality of the StringBuilder I want to be tested.) Unfortunately this does not work in the example below. In other tests I have a workaround by setting the instance variables with an EasyMock instance, but with this example I am unable to do this, because it is a locally instantiated object I care about.

Who can help me out?

The class to be tested:

```
package example.easymock

public class Example {

    public String exampleMethod() {
        StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
        string.append("hello");
        return string.toString();
    }
}
```

The testing class:

```
package example.easymock

import needed classes

public class ExampleTest {

    @Test
    public void exampleMethodTest() {
        StringBuilder stringMock = EasyMock.createMock();
        Example example = new Example();
        stringMock.append("hello");
        EasyMock.expect(stringMock.toString()).andReturn("hi");

        EasyMock.replay(stringMock);

        example.exampleMethod();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just `EasyMock` it's going to be impossible. `PowerMock` does contain power to do that however:

```
expectNew(StringBuilder.class).andReturn(stringMock);
```

You need to set up PowerMock configuration correctly for that to work of course - see more [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor)

That doesn't change the fact, that exactly this impossibility is what (in part) lead to widely adopting [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) as a design principle. Also, as a rule, any method you can not test is a method that could be refactored to be better (and testable). PowerMock should only be used for tests when code itself can't be changed to be better.

That is of course assuming that `StringBuilder` is just an example and not literally what you're trying to do. If it is - don't bother, you can assume that any methods that are part of language libraries work as advertised.

Comment: PowerMock can infact mock constructors of classes. So it *is* possible with PowerMock.

Comment: @dav1d damn, that thing is powerfull, true.

Comment: Just to add on how to do it with TestNG+PowerMock+Mockito incase it is helpful: Prepare the class you want to test: ` `@PrepareForTest(SomeService.class)` then just "mock" the constructor: `whenNew(Date.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(now);`